# Проект asp.mvc не загружает изображения

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Столкнулся с проблемой на ровном месте:
Мне нужно вывести на страницу график. График я формирую с помощью `System.Web.Helpers` (объект класса `Chart` ) и сохраняю в файл на диске.
Потом в `PartialView` через `Ajax` запрос хочу вывести изображение на страницу.
Столкнулся с тем, что проект не выводит изображения. Вообще никакие. Контроллер отрабатывает, изображение на  диске - то, которое нужно, а вот в частичное представление я его вывести не могу.
Что я делаю не так?

Контроллер (опущен конструктор):

```
 public ActionResult Index(string url)
    {
        manager = new VMManager();
        manager.VM = (SiteVM)manager.GetVM(url);
        var tempvm = manager.VM;
        return View(tempvm);
    }

    // рисование графика:
   public ActionResult Wrapper (string pattern)
    {
        if (pattern == "test") return null;
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        string param = pattern;
        var PVM = manager.VM.PageResults.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PageAddress == pattern);
        var filepath = @"~/Views/Tool/chart.jpg";

     //   if (System.IO.File.Exists(filepath)) System.IO.File.Delete(filepath);

        var chart = new System.Web.Helpers.Chart(width: 700, height: 300, theme: ChartTheme.Green)
            .AddTitle("Графическое представление времени обработки запроса")
            .AddSeries(
                        name: "graph",
                        chartType: "Line",
                        xValue: new[] { "запрос 1", "запрос 2", "запрос 3", "запрос 4", "запрос 5" },
                        yValues: PVM.AttemptsTime.ToArray())
            // .Write();
            .Save(path: filepath);

        return PartialView("ShowPageResultInChart", new { path = filepath });

    }
```

Основное представление (фрагменты):
Здесь должен быть выведен график. Это строчка в dive

```
  @Html.Action("Wrapper", new { pattern = "test" })
```

Здесь вызывается Ajax-запрос:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.PageResults)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Ajax.ActionLink(item.PageAddress, "Wrapper", new { pattern = item.PageAddress },
             new AjaxOptions
             {
                 UpdateTargetId = "ChartData",
                 LoadingElementId = "LoadingIndicator"
             }
                )
            </td>
```

Частичное представление - одна строка, тэг img: (даю только внутренности тэга img)
`img src="chart.jpg" alt="Graph"`

Файл есть, студия его тоже видит. Но на страницу не выводит. Ни Firefox, ни Chrome. Пробовал абсолютный путь  не помогло. Пробовал "левый" рисунок (думал, может этот блокируется методом контроллера) - не помогло. В сети ответа тоже не нашел.
  Проект создавался как Web->ASP.NET->Empty. Может в настройках проекта что-то включить надо - не знаю

Comment: `img src="chart.jpg"` -> `img src="@Model.path"`

Comment: Вы сохраняете файл в ~/Views/Tool/chart.jpg а в src прописываете текущий каталог. Пропишите полностью.

Comment: @A K: Это я знаю,сначала пытался правильно сделать. Но в текущем каталоге тоже есть такой файл и он тоже не выводится.

Comment: А что такое текущий каталог? У вас какой url в браузере показывается? Наверняка /controllername/actionname/ а никак не views/tool Вы пробовали просто в браузере открыть url http://localhost/views/tools/chart.jpg

Comment: @A K: Текущий каталог -  каталог, в котором находится PartialView. Url браузер не открывает. Но и не показывает, потому что Ajax запрос

Comment: Просто складывать картинку в папку View (а для этой папки создан отдельный web.config и что у вас там написано -- бог знает) не очень хорошо. Я для статики выделяю отдельную папку и прописываю для неё отдельный web.config с дополнительным кешированием.

Comment: @A K: Сначала я положил его в отдельную папку. Потом, когда не смог открыть  поначалу грешил на кривые руки и неправильно прописанные пути. Поэтому, для отладки и с целью исключения фактора кривых рук, положил копию в  каталог с представлениями.

Comment: @Igor: А как model прописать? Если просто заменить код на Ваш -  не работает

Comment: Исключите для начала неопределённость того, что вы думаете, что ваше понимание какой каталог текущий совпадает с пониманием веб-сервера. Положите файл явно в папку Asdf и пропишите адрес от корня сайта до папки Asdf

Comment: Никогда не пробовал класть картинки в папку View, но вот сейчас ради эксперимента сделал. У меня тоже картинка не видится. Положите в какую-нибудь новую папку или в папку Content -- уж на ней-то будет нормально. Только прописывайте пути полностью, чтобы исключить неправильную трактовку

Comment: А, ну ещё бы. В web.config для папки Views по умолчанию идёт только BlockViewHandler с System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler -- хоть наобкладывайся туда картинок -- всё равно ничего не увидишь.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался. Все-таки кривые руки + защита от дурака.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых. Не складывайте изображения в подпапки для Views. По умолчанию в web.config для папки Views идёт правило:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Поэтому картинку вы там не сможете увидеть. Положите картинку в какую-нибудь другую папку, например, в Content.

Во-вторых о текущем каталоге. Если вы открыли в браузере url https://localhost:12345/Product/Detailed?productID=1 то текущий каталог это никак не ~/Views/Product/ -- а текущий каталог это /Product/ и Views вообще ни при чём, забудьте о нём. Вот если у вас картинка chart.jpg лежит в каталоге /Products то тогда вы можете на странице /Product/Detailed подключать по относительному пути src="chart.jpg". Не уверены? Прописывайте абсолютный url от корня сайта src="/Product/chart.jpg"

И если не уверены, то прописывайте абсолютные url к картинке. А для начала -- просто откройте в браузере url картинки, чтобы увидеть, что она там реально есть.

И ещё, на будущее. Лучше создать сразу виртуальную папку для автоматически сгенерированных картинок. И гит не будет видеть лишние файлы и на реальном хостинге удобно.